# How to create a moving object from where I clicked

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing and I'm trying to create a Space Invaders kind of mechanic where I shoot a bullet from the ship, however I am having trouble trying to make the bullet shoot from the x coordinate where I click and continue going on the X-axis up and away from the ship. I'm attempting to use mouseClicked but I wind up with the bullet either following the mouseX or not moving at all on the Y-axis, any help is appreciated thanks.

```java
Hero theHero;
Bullet theBullet;

void setup(){
  size(300,600);
  theHero = new Hero(color(255,0,0),mouseX,mouseY);
  theBullet = new Bullet(color(255,255,0),300,600,-4);
}

void draw(){
background(255);
theHero.move();
theHero.display();
theBullet.displayb();
theBullet.mouseClicked();
}

class Hero {
 color c;
 float xpos;
 float ypos;

Hero(color tempC,float tempXpos, float tempYpos){
  c = tempC;
  xpos = tempXpos;
  ypos = tempYpos;
}

 void display() {
  stroke(0);
  fill(c);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(xpos, ypos, 20, 10);
}

void move() {
 xpos = mouseX;
 ypos = 580;

 }
}

class Bullet {
color c;
float xpos;
float ypos;
float yspeed;

Bullet(color tempC, float tempXpos, float tempYpos, float tempYspeed) {
  c = tempC;
  xpos = tempXpos;
  ypos = tempYpos;
  yspeed = tempYspeed;
}

void displayb() {
   stroke(0);
   fill(c);
   rectMode(CENTER);
   rect(xpos, ypos, 5, 5);
}



void mouseClicked(){
  xpos = mouseX;
  ypos = ypos + yspeed;
  if (ypos < 0) {
    ypos = 580;
    xpos = mouseX;

  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are calling the mouseClicked() method every frame of the draw loop. Constantly changing the xpos of the bullet to the mouseX position. In order to remove theBullet.mouseClicked() from the draw() function.

You also need to create an array of bullet objects. And draw each of them. In the mouseClicked() (which is called everytime a mouse is clicked) create a new Bullet object with the xpos of the current Hero position. This should look  like this.

```java
void mouseClicked(){
    bulletCount++;
    float startX = theHero.xpos;
    bullets[bulletCount] = new Bullet(color(255,0,0),startX,theHero.ypos, -5 /*YSPEED*/);
}
```

In order to create and draw all of the Bullet objects you need an array. This can be created and displayed like so:

```java
Hero theHero;
public Bullet[] bullets = new Bullet[10000];
public static int bulletCount = 0;
void setup(){
  size(300,600);
  theHero = new Hero(color(255,0,0),mouseX,mouseY);
}

void draw(){
background(255);
for(int i = 1; i <= bulletCount;i++){
  bullets[i].updatePos();
  bullets[i].displayb();
}
theHero.move();
theHero.display();
}
```

Ive also added a updatePos() to the Bullet object which increments its y position by the y speed every frame. If you want the full code just copy this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/2CpLPTnQ

Comment: Thank you so much!